# how to add an eventlistener for every element of a div?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I'm trying to add a eventlistenner to every element of this div.
But I can't seems to able to access every element of this div.
The console.log can print out the table as a list.
but it shows an error after I try to use forEach method. 
Why would that be?

```js
let table = document.getElementsByClassName('pixel');
console.log(table);

table.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item)
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The returned value of table is an `HtmlCollection` rather than an array so you can't use the `Array.prototype.forEach` method.

Instead, you can iterate over the divs like so:

```js
let table = document.getElementsByClassName('pixel');
console.log(table);

for (let item of table) {
  console.log(item);
};
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="pixel">
    P1
  </div>
  <div class="pixel">
    P2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed to for of method. but weirdly. It still can't print out the result. though, this time,It did not show any error message.

Comment: Have you tried swapping out your `console.log` for actually adding the handler? The handler in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g3mfujk2/) works.

Comment: yes,I tried. it worked on w3c web editor and stack overflow's editor. But after i put it back to my code. It weirdly does not work. And it does not show error message. I'm using chrome brower and node.js live-server module. Wonder if that affects the result.

Comment: I find out what goes wrong. I put the script in the head section. The script gets load before HTML element gets load.